# Swift: Use variable in another .swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make an app to display information about trains.

I've got two files, TrainViewController.swift and TrainDataManager.swift.

Here's the beginning of the code for TrainViewController.swift:

```
class TrainViewController: UIViewController {

@IBAction func Train100(sender: UIButton) {
    var num = "100"
    }
```

[...]

And in TrainDataManager.swift I have

```
let URL = "http://myawesomeapi.net/rqst?number=\(num)&otherthing=1"
```

Of course I have a "Use of unresolved identifier 'num'" error.
I tried a lot of things found on the Internet but I can't access "num" in TrainDataManager.swift.

Comment: you can use singleton.

Answer (score 2):

`num` is a locally scoped variable - it only exists within the `Train100` function.

If you want to use a local variable in another function, you should pass it as an argument. Your `TrainDataManger` can add a method like this:

```
func getTrainInfo(trainID : String) {
    let URL = "http://myawesomeapi.net/rqst?number=\(trainID)&otherthing=1"
}
```

Then call the function, passing the appropriate value:

```
@IBAction func Train100(sender: UIButton) {
    var num = "100"
    myTrainDataManager.getTrainInfo(num)
}
```

This will call `getTrainInfo(_)`, passing `"100"` as an argument.

Comment: You can also declare the variable at a global level to access it in multiple places but I would never suggest that to someone. It makes me cringe just thinking about it.

Comment: @CharlesCaldwell Yeah, I almost included that but decided not to

Comment: @AaronBrager Thanks a lot for your help, but now I have "Use of unresolved identifier 'myTrainDataManager'" in my TrainViewController. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: @AaronBrager It works perfectly, I just have to remove the "my" you added before TrainDataManager. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is turn num into a public variable like this:

```
class TrainViewController: UIViewController {

var num 
@IBAction func Train100(sender: UIButton) {
    num = "100"
}
```

and in the other class you have to create an object for the Train View Controller class and refer to num like this:

```
class TrainDataManger... {
    func ... {
        let tvc : TrainViewController = TrainViewController()
        let URL = "http://myawesomeapi.net/rqst?number=\(tvc.num)&otherthing=1"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I put "var num" I got "Type annotation missing in pattern"

Comment: To fix that, simply write: var num:String = String()

Comment: Thanks ! The code works, but tvc.num is received as empty. ( http://myawesomeapi.net/rqst?number=&otherthing=1 is loaded.)

Comment: It's received as empty because the button actually don't update the var …, tvc.num will fetch the first "var num:String = String()" even if I press the button

Answer (score -1):

You can use like this one. `Singleton` style. Create `Trainer NSObject`.

Trainer.swift

```
import Foundation

class Trainer : NSObject{

    var num : Int!

    init(num: Int) {
        self.num = num
    }

    func getNum() -> Int {
        return num;
    }

    func setNum(num:Int){
        self.num = num;
    }
}
```

TrainViewController.swift

```
class TrainViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let instanceTrainer = Trainer()
}

@IBAction func Train100(sender: UIButton) {
    instanceTrainer.setNum(100)
    }
```

TrainDataManger.swift

```
var num: Int

num = instanceTrainer.getNum()

let URL = "http://myawesomeapi.net/rqst?number=\(num)&otherthing=1"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got in TrainViewController.swift "Missing argument for parameter 'num' in call" for let instanceTrainer = Trainer()